# undefined element declaration 'xs:schema'

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java, wsimport

I am completely new to web service stuff.

I have to write rest web service client for a web service. The web service runs fine on SoapUI. WSDL file for the URL is provided to me. But when I add the wsdl file in my Eclipse project, it gives compilation error

```
src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:schema'. It was detected that 'xs:schema' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///E:/Ashish%20Workspace/HATStoLSAMS%20Webservice/HATS2LSAMSWS/WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdl/CorpsiteService.svc.wsdl'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'xs:schema' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///E:/Ashish%20Workspace/HATStoLSAMS%20Webservice/HATS2LSAMSWS/WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdl/CorpsiteService.svc.wsdl'.
```

I googled a lot to get rid of these error but nothing worked.
If I ignore the errors and try creating stubs using wsimport as well as wsdl2java commands
it gives error

```
[ERROR] undefined element declaration 'xs:schema'
line 1 of http://chec.local/STAR.WCF/CorpsiteService.svc?singlewsdl
```

I am using below command to generate stubs

```
wsimport -d e:\test -s E:\wssrc http://chec.local/STAR.WCF/CorpsiteService.svc?singlewsdl -wsdllocation "../../../../../WEB-INF/wsdl/CorpsiteService.svc.wsdl"
```

I am stuck at this point and have been struggling on to this the whole day.
Any help regarding this would be really helpful

Answer (score 10):

The solution to this appears to be supply alternate bindings for `xs:schema` as described in https://metro.java.net/2.1/guide/Dealing_with_schemas_that_are_not_referenced.html

Specifically, for the http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema which is often imported into the namespace `xs`, there is some additional work that needs to be done.

The command would be: `wsimport -b  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd  -b  customization.xjb  something.wsdl`

customization.xjb linked from the above is at https://www.java.net//blog/kohsuke/archive/20070228/xsd.xjb or copied from below

This customization exists to handle some naming conflicts that might arise from using the schema Schema (which is imported as the same name space in multiple schemas).

customization.xjb

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          version="2.0">

  <globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple />
  </globalBindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:complexType">
    <class name="ComplexTypeType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:simpleType">
    <class name="SimpleTypeType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:group">
    <class name="GroupType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:attributeGroup">
    <class name="AttributeGroupType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:element">
    <class name="ElementType"/>
  </bindings>

  <bindings scd="~xsd:attribute">
    <class name="attributeType"/>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

I have tried this with these files and the associated `-b` parameters to `wsimport` and have gotten (apparently) past this error (and on to other ones).  That said, I'm not 100% certain that my new errors are not in part caused by this (and thus this wouldn't be a complete answer).  Without the actual wsdl causing the problem, one can only take a reasonable guess as to solving the problem (and on to the next one).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelT for the concise answer and the provided links, that solved the problem for me.

Comment: @jlr thank you for letting me know it was useful.  With the xsd that lead me to this, I never could solve the errors and went over to using the apache axis library for doing the client that was more forgiving / dynamic in its client.  That said, it was also more dynamic in its client and didn't have the easy static types that wsimport gives you.

Comment: I did not use `wsimport` but Apache CXF's `wsdl2java` tool to generate these. I stay away from Glassfish as I had some unrelated problems with it in the past (regarding custom data serialization that did not work no matter what I tried, CXF worked out of the box!).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using maven-jaxb2-plugin instead -b provide needed URL as additional schema in schemas:

```
<schema>
  <url>https://example.com/WebService.asmx?WSDL</url>
</schema>
<schema>
  <url>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd</url>
</schema>
```

You can even save it in resources so it is picked up automatically

Comment: This solved the issue here for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue, resolved by just adding one line into maven plugin

```
<args> 
    <arg>-b</arg>
    <arg>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd</arg>
</args>
```

My maven plugin is given below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>periodictableaccessws</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <args>
                    <arg>-b</arg>
                    <arg>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd</arg>
                </args>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>doosdaas.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <packageName>com.dss.doosdaas</packageName>
                <vmArgs>
                    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</vmArg>
                    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                </vmArgs>
                <!--   <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb</bindingDirectory>
                   <bindingFiles>
                       <bindingFile>jaxb_binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                   </bindingFiles>-->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I face this kind of error when I had to consume some of UE Taxations Customs web services. In previous projects I had used the solution proposed by [user289086](http://user289086)

But for recents projects I had used another solution also based in bindings but shorter, where I use the Wrapper-style rules described here [Using JAXB Data Binding](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#jaxws_wrapper).

1- Create a binding file with the following content and add it to META-INF folder:

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

2- Create Web service reference from wsdl using wsimport(in my case I use the Netbeans IDE WS Client Assistant that use wsimport in the background) for the following service for example:
[UE CheckTinService](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tin/checkTinService.wsdl)

Note: First maybe the process of wsimport could be raise and error or not, but the difference of adding or not the previous binding is easy to check.

3- Add the binding reference to the corresponding jaxws-maven-plugin execution in the .pom file. For the example it stays like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tin/checkTinService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <packageName></packageName>
                <vmArgs>
                    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                </vmArgs>
                <wsdlLocation>https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tin/checkTinService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/checkTinService.stale</staleFile>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/TaxationCustomsWsImportBindings.xml</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
            </configuration>
            <id>wsimport-generate-checkTinService</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    ...
```

You can see the exactly configuration for using the binding file created before:

```
<bindingFiles>
       <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/TaxationCustomsWsImportBindings.xml</bindingFile>
</bindingFiles>
```

4- Finally turn to refresh de WS Reference and the changes will be applied to the process of wsimport.